# How can a plane of existence contain a pocket realm larger than itself without being destroyed?

Tags: physics, super-powers

A reality warper has the power to manipulate reality. Users can create, shape and manipulate reality just by thinking about it, and may alter something as tangible as physics and the universe to something inconceivable like logic. The reality of the mortal realm is held together by a series of crisscrossing strings that are interconnected. These strings are tied to everything living and nonliving within the realm, connecting all things within a realm to each other, similar to a tapestry. A reality warper can see and mentally manipulate these strings to change the world around them, altering the physical and nonphysical to suit their purposes. To others, they can seemingly create things from nothing and can just as easily erase them from existence. This practically makes them a god in the eyes of others.

A warper can use his altering abilities to terraform an entire realm in his image, including climate, atmosphere, laws of physics, etc. Despite the popular belief however, they are not all powerful. A warper has complete control over his or her domain, which encompasses an area of 500 feet in all directions around them. In this space, their power is absolute, as they wield direct control over the area around them. This domain is a relatively small. Therefore, these individuals can extend this space to hundreds of times its initial size without expanding their initial domain. To an outsider, this domain measures the same feet as it always has been. However, the domain is far larger and may even be more massive than the original realm.

Imagine a small container like a jar that contains water, with the jar being the realm and the liquid being the domain of the user. As the amount of water increases, it pushed on the inside of the container,  straining the constraints of its size. At some point, the jar must either expand to contain the water, or risk being burst open and destroyed, allowing the liquid to escape. A realm's size is finite and cannot expand due to the laws of the universe that the gods put in place. A warper extending his domain past a certain threshold risks destroying reality entirely, killing everything in the process.

How can a warper prevent this from happening?

Comment: That realm is from where the designers of the [TARDIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS) took inspiration. Seriously speaking, I do not see the problem. The "realm", whatever that means, is entirely made up, with strings, warpers and bizarre metaphysics; it also allows for containers which have an inner volume much larger than their outer volume, so what? (And in the real world, we all have lungs which have an inside area very much larger than their outside area.)

Comment: Current understanding of topology seems to indicate that this just isn't the case. You can of course make up any rules you like for your own fictional worlds, but if those are like ours, it probably is possible for a larger volume of space to exist within an area smaller than what we would intuitively think possible. If he's able to create space itself, then this is the very definition of what he does. You might get some really funky values of π though.

Comment: I agree with AlexP on that you'll most probably have to think it by yourself. Indeed, as you said yourself : "In this space, their power is absolute, as they wield direct control over the area around them.". If they have godlike powers in this area, then they could alter the rules to say that 1 meter "outside" is 1km "inside".

Comment: This freedom brings us to the innate contradiction of your world configuration : They either have total control of their domain and this might affect the outside world,(e.g. : my domain is a star, so anything outside is sucked and burnt to a crisp!) or they can't do as much as you proclaim. Contradictions are not bad, but if you want to deepen that aspect, you'll have to choose eventually.

Comment: Use the Banach–Tarski paradox in reverse.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of very different answers and no good way to say which is best.  I think this question needs some "best answer" qualifiers to avoid a close.

Comment: If they can warp logic, they can invalidate any reason given here why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 13):

Because more dimensions can carry more stuff inside.

In a 2D realm you can only hold as much water as you have square meters available. 1 cm<sup>2</sup> of space can carry 1 cm<sup>2</sup> of water.

In a 3D realm you can hold 1 cm<sup>3</sup> of water. That is a magnitude more even though it's technically the same amount of space as the 2D realm except that you have one extra dimension tacked on.

Your warpers can manipulate the laws of physics, they are essentially adding dimensions to the space around them to make it larger. The way they do this makes sure that for themselves and other (spatial) 3D creatures it looks like "just" a larger space rather than the weird spatial dimensions that have already been theorized.

Comment: I thought at this too ^^, but I don't have the answer on one thing though : If your domain is X meter long, could it be possible to walk more than X meter in a straight line, and without observing weird things like (hyper)spheres or (hyper)cubes appearing out of nowhere?

Comment: @Tortliena probably not. That dimension isn't changed. There are just more dimensions. I think it can be compared to a swimming pool. You can fill it with water. The moment you fill it with water at that moment, and fill the swimming pool again a second later, the time dimension, you have 2 swimming pools. There are possibly many more dimensions we don't know or understand, allowing reality warpers to cram ungodly amounts in a small room. It also allows them to fill it with different things.

Comment: AKA Skuld's Space Doubler in Ah! My Goddess.

Comment: @Tortliena well, if we take the 2D/3D example: If you're a 2D Being used to 2D space, you probably don't have the senses to perceive 3D. So if I as a reality warper have access to the third dimension, I could just fold up a HUGE 2D expanse and stuff it into the 3D space - just gotta make sure there's no folds, those would probably get noticed. Bends? You're a 2D Being, you don't have a concept of "up" and "down", so you might get "this feels weird" at best. So I could imagine the benders having access to more dimensions meaning they can fold up a large 3D space in a way that it fits.

Comment: @Trioxidane I feel perhaps a better suggestion is that a pool a cm deep and a pool a mile deep look cosmetically the same when full of any opaque liquid. So the reality warper can essentially deepen their pool, allowing vastly more volume of liquid in the same square-footage of pool.

Comment: A cube of water is far more than a square of water. Like way more than a magnitude larger. How would you even determine the volume of the 2d square? Is it a one molecule thick layer of water?

Answer (score 6):

**How many numbers are between 0 and 1?**

I like Demigan's answer about dimensions which I think would be the stock answer - the warper accesses additional 3 dimension spaces thru a 4th or higher dimension conduit.

But what if the warper just makes things smaller?  The same space would look larger to me if I were smaller.  My clothes would also get smaller, or they would fall off.  It is the [Kandor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kandor_(comics)) principle.

This is how the warper does it.  The warper can shrink all things within a space such that the space seems larger.  That does not mean the space fills up with fascinating new things of its own accord as might be the case in the multidimensional scenario.  It might be like having a date in an abandoned train station instead of a restaurant.  But maybe the warper can fill the space up with interesting decorations.  Small ones, of course, to fit.

Comment: "How many numbers are between 0 and 1?" <- I really love this question because it has so many possible answers.  If you ask a lay person, the answer is probably ∞.  If you ask an accountant, the answer is 99.  If you ask a programmer, the answer depends on how many bits you commit to tracking the fractional part of your float. But if you ask a physicist, you just get an awkward shoulder shrug, since we really have no clue if spacetime is even discrete or continuous. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35674/is-time-continuous-or-discrete

Answer (score 4):

### Fractal mapping

[image: A hyperbolic planar tiling - each coloured shape "feels" like the same size to an occupant]

You want to maximise the number of points reachable from your "warp(er) core" with a finite distance. That's easy enough if you can mess with how space connects.

Alternatively, if the space only has to be within a certain distance of the warper's body, they can will that they have snowflake-like tendril-arms.

And if you're getting desperate to preserve some arbitrary criterion I've misunderstood, you can shrink-ray everything inside or edit physics so that the space can be reused repeatedly.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that your image is of a [rhombitriheptagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombitriheptagonal_tiling) of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. It's an intentional "error", to help convey the idea of mapping an infinite plane to within a finite radius.

Answer (score 4):

### The pocket realm is a spacetime bubble

The effects of gravity on space time is often compared to stretching a sheet.  Although the Cartesian area around an object stays the area of spacetime expands.

[image]

Since Spacetime can stretch, and there is no known limit to how much it can stretch, then a warper can just stretch space-time to its desired size, and in very unexpected ways since he can modify the laws of physics.  Now, the big problem with making a pocket realm  bigger than 500m is that you will want a nice flat usable bottom so you're not getting ripped apart by gravitational shear. But this means that you need to invert Space time as you stretch it.  Since the slope of space time hits infinity just at the point it inverts, it means that the outer boundary of your realm becomes an event horizon similar to a black hole.  It also means that the edges of your pocket realm would be like an untraversable white hole because you'd have to move against an infinite slope to reach the inverted spacetime; so, things can get into your realm, but only other warpers would be able break the rules of spacetime to get out.

[image]

If you don't like leaving black holes lying around, it may also be possible to pinch the opening down to a subatomic size escentially separating your dimension from the parent dimension.

Answer (score 3):

**It gets progressively harder to expand the realm as it gets larger**

When you inflate a bicycle tire, there is more air inside the container than in a space of the same size outside it, but the more air you shove in, the more it shoves back. If you push it far enough, eventually either your tire pops or your pump's valve ruptures, depending on which one is stronger. Your Warper is a bicycle pump, and its domain is a tire made of three-inch-thick steel. It's obvious which one breaks first.

To that end, you should make it obvious to your readers that Warpers expend effort to change their surroundings, and can "feel" things changing, like you feel material shifting when you mold a clay pot. They can keep straining, but their Reality Muscles can only lift so much before tearing themselves apart.

Answer (score 3):

**The mage is zipping the reality inside the pocket realm**

You can see that reality could be seen as a kind of "information". In the normal 3d space, the matter is located in the space very inefficiently. In the same 3D space, it is possible to rearrange all the components of matter (atoms or even quarks and elemntary particles) in a more space-efficient way.

Think of a [BMP image versus a PNG image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats), where 90% of pixels have the same color: BMP is a simpler and easier to understand than PNG, but needs more bits to codify the same information. PNG is not readable and requires more processing power in order to recreate the image, but also requires less bits.

Similarly to Willk answer, the reality inside the pocket realm is shrunk in size, but in this case it is also "rearranged" so that it occupies even less space. Rearranging the reality is very difficult: you have to make sure that, in spite of this rearrangement, the physics still functions like in the normal reality, otherwise there could be unpredictable effects on all people inside the realm. So only the most skilled mages can perform this expansion of space.

Answer (score 1):

**Nested realms.**

If a pocket realm can exist, then a pocket-inside a pocket can double the space. Multiple pockets, having their entrances from the first pocket can double, triple, quadruple the space available and so on until there is no more space to create entrances side-by side.  This requires a certain amount of skill and power to achieve.

It's not inconceivable that some learned mage, having studied the mysteries for most of their life, might summon a pocket within a pocket within a pocket realm.

There have been rumors about such things where great wealth and objects of power have been hidden, those rumors have been stirring excitement in Neophyte Warpers for generations-on-end. They always provoke a wry smile on the face of the masters, who know it's just a youthful dream of power and avarice (at least it makes them pay attention to their studies with wide-eyed enthusiasm).... but some of them still wonder... what if? Then chuckle at their own foolishness.

Answer (score 0):

### Stretch your 3D into the 4D

As [Demigan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/48354/demigan) has already said. You can have your Warpers have the ability to influence an area around them by 500ft in 4D instead than 3D.

Adding to his response, you can surely make anyone walk in a very long straight line. To make this simple, imagine a 2D world, where people can walk only on X/Y axis. In this world Warpers are able to influence a **3D** area of 500ft around them. [Imagine a sphere, cut in half by a plane and moving on said plane](https://images.app.goo.gl/Z2NTkFa66iq8Ey456). Only the Warper is aware of this 3D space.

The question now is: how they can use this space?

The Warper can make use of the additional space, by stretching the 2D space into the 3D. As an example, imagine the plane that usually "cut" the sphere in half, being now on the top part of the sphere external surface. The total surface area is now increased: to go from one side to the other, you have to move on the surface of the sphere instead that "inside" of it. This is a simple example, the Warper can make all shapes he wants and even fold the plane an infinite (or limited by his ability) amount of times and create an infinitely long surface.

Mind that the Warper is at the center of the sphere (the area he can manipulate is around him), so the plane he creates has to pass through it (and this invalidate our first simple example).

Also, you have to define if the Warper is only able to "stretch" the plane (not properly stretching because you are creating new spaces) or he can also detach the border points freely, making contact with the space outside his sphere impossible (as an example creating a sphere inside his sphere, on which people walk over and over on the same sceneries).

Now make the original 2D plane a 3D world and the circular plane touched by the 3D sphere a 3D environment touched by a HyperSphere.